# Coefficients of dummy variables in multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I am struggling with interpreting coefficients from a multiple regression analysis with multiple categorical (dummy) variables. I am running a linear mixed model with biodiversity (`LnS_Add1`) as independent variable, and several continuous and categorical dependent variables.

With a single categorical/dummy variable (e.g. `LnS_Add1 ~ AREA_AM_2.5 + System_Type3`; where `AREA_AM_2.5` is continuous and `System_Type3` is categorical with 3 levels, i.e. *Arable*, *Grassland* and *Orchard*) this is pretty straightforward. In this case the intercept represents the mean of the reference dummy variable (e.g. *Arable*) and the mean of the 2nd and 3rd levels *Grassland* and *Orchard* can be calculated manually by adding intercept to the slope coefficient.

```
globmod1 <- lmer(LnS_Add1 ~ AREA_AM_2.5 + System_Type3 + 
     (1|Study_Code/Pair_Code), data1_plant)
summary(globmod1)
```

Which returns

```
Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)            0.3585534  0.1238470   2.895
AREA_AM_2.5            0.0004256  0.0001371   3.104
System_Type3Grassland -0.5227684  0.0915722  -5.709
System_Type3Orchard   -0.4057969  0.5477567  -0.741
```

To get a summary output that shows the means of both *Arable*, *Grassland* and *Orchard* in R I suppress the intercept by adding a -1 (or +0) to the model.

```
globmod1.coef <- lmer(LnS_Add1 ~ AREA_AM_2.5 + System_Type3 -1 +
                   (1|Study_Code/Pair_Code), data1_plant)
summary(globmod1.coef)
```

Which returns:

```
Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value
AREA_AM_2.5            0.0004256  0.0001371   3.104
System_Type3Arable     0.3585534  0.1238470   2.895
System_Type3Grassland -0.1642149  0.1341851  -1.224
System_Type3Orchard   -0.0472434  0.5457304  -0.087
```

But what do I do if I have multiple categorical variables (e.g. `LnS_Add1 ~ AREA_AM_2.5 + System_Type3 + Habitat2`; where Habitat2 is a categorical variable with 3 levels, i.e. *Farm aggregated*, *Outside field*, and *Within field*)?. Now the intercept represents the mean of the reference level of a combination of `System_Type3` and `Habitat2` (e.g. all data in arable systems and measured at farm aggregate level). But what I am interested in are the means for the different levels of each of my 2 categorical variables, holding everything else constant.

How do I create a summary table that contains means of all levels of all categorical variables in my model? The -1 command doesnt help me anymore, as it removes the intercept but the intercept now represents a mean of 2 reference dummy variables. I am only interested here in the fixed effect estimates, not in any hypothesis testing.

Comment: This question isn't really about how to code in R. It is about understanding how multiple categorical variables are represented in regression models. IMO, it should be considered on-topic here.

Comment: I believe `lsmeans` in package lmerTest could be what you are after.

Comment: @Roland - thanks for the suggestion. I tried `lsmeans` out but when used on an `lmer` object it always gives the error message: `Error in as.data.frame.default(VarCorr(model)) : 
  cannot coerce class ""VarCorr.merMod"" to a data.frame`. And I couldn't find help on this error online. In addition to the question of how to do this in R, as @gung pointed out, this is not just an R question, as I am also just generally interested in how to interpret multiple categorical variables in regressions...

Comment: `lsmeans` from package `lsmeans` works with an `lmer` object. And the [documentation for the `lsmeans` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf) does a good job at explaining what it is doing.